# Concatenate two columns in pandas with NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 
                        'colA': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                        'colB': ['D', np.nan, 'E']}))

df

    ID  colA   colB
0   ID1 A      D
1   ID2 B      NaN
2   ID3 C      E
```

I want to combine the two columns, however keep only column A if column B is NaN. Hence Expected output is

```
    ID  colA    colB    colC
0   ID1 A       D       A_D
1   ID2 B       NaN     B
2   ID3 C       E       C_E
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Idea is add `_` to second column with `_`, so after replace missing value by empty string is not added `_` for missing values:

```
df['colC'] = df['colA'] + ('_' + df['colB']).fillna('')
print (df)
    ID colA colB colC
0  ID1    A    D  A_D
1  ID2    B  NaN    B
2  ID3    C    E  C_E
```

If not sure where are missing values (in `colA` or `colB`):

```
df['colC'] = (df['colA'].fillna('') + '_' + df['colB'].fillna('')).str.strip('_')
```

Also is possible test each column separately:

```
m1 = df['colA'].isna()
m2 = df['colB'].isna()

df['colC'] = np.select([m1, m2, m1 & m2], 
                        [df['colB'], df['colA'], np.nan], 
                        default=df['colA'] + '_' + df['colB'])
print (df)

    ID colA colB colC
0  ID1    A    D  A_D
1  ID2    B  NaN    B
2  ID3  NaN    E    E
3  ID4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

Learned this from Datanovice's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62681510/6660373):

```
df['col_c'] = df[['colA', 'colB']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg('_'.join)
df
```

---

```
    ID  colA    colB    col_c
0   ID1 A       D       A_D
1   ID2 B       NaN     B
2   ID3 C       E       C_E
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Series.str.cat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) accessor.

- `sep='_'` - Separator to be put between the two strings.
- `na_rep=''` - To ignore `NaN` value, it's None or string value to replace in place of null values.
- `str.replace('_$', '')`- To remove underscore at the end.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = (pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'],
                        'colA': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                        'colB': ['D', np.nan, 'E']}))


df['colC']= df.colA.str.cat(df.colB,sep="_",na_rep='').str.replace('_$', '')
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

```
    ID colA colB colC
0  ID1    A    D  A_D
1  ID2    B  NaN    B
2  ID3    C    E  C_E
```